# How to configure TidFTP with SSL?

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I have a little FTP client I wrote to manage my files on my bluehost.com account. Now that I have migrated to a new hosting company, my program will connect, but that is all it will do.

After connecting, I tried to get an inventory of the root files; the program hangs for a bit and finally produces a "read time out".

After researching, I came to the conclusion (possibly incorrectly) that this had something to do with SSL (which I have available to me through my new host). I added a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component to my form, assigned it to myFTP and set `UseTLS = utUseExplicitTLS`.

Now, when I try to connect, I get an 10054 error. I have not been able to find any examples as to how to configure this connection.

Here is the code:

```pascal
unit ct_FTP_Test;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Controls, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
  IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdFTP, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdIOHandler,
  IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdAntiFreezeBase,
  IdFTPCommon, IdAntiFreeze;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnConnectFTP: TButton;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    mem: TMemo;
    btnShowFolder: TButton;
    idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    myFTP: TIdFTP;
    edHost: TEdit;
    edUser: TEdit;
    edPassword: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    idAntiFreeze: TIdAntiFreeze;
    edPort: TEdit;
    Label6: TLabel;
    ckbUseSSL: TCheckBox;
    procedure btnConnectFTPClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnShowFolderClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure GetFolderInventory;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.GetFolderInventory;
var DirList : TStringList;
begin
  if (not myFTP.Connected) then
    begin
      Label2.Caption := 'You are not connected...';
      Exit;
    end;

  try
    try
      Label4.Caption := 'Going to root...';
      myFTP.ChangeDir('/');
      Label4.Caption := 'At root, getting DirList...';

      DirList := TStringList.Create;
      myFTP.List(DirList, '', True);

      Label2.Caption := '';
      Label4.Caption := IntToStr(DirList.Count) + ' files and folders found';

      mem.Lines.Assign(DirList);
    except on e:Exception do
      begin
        Label4.Caption := 'Unable to show contents';
        Label2.Caption := e.Message;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(DirList);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnShowFolderClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetFolderInventory;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnConnectFTPClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    Label2.Caption := '';
    Label4.Caption := '';

    if (myFTP.Connected) then
      myFTP.Disconnect;

    if (edHost.Text = '') then
      begin
        edHost.SetFocus;
        Label4.Caption := 'Host required.';
        Exit;
      end;

    if (edUser.Text = '') then
      begin
        edUser.SetFocus;
        Label4.Caption := 'User required.';
        Exit;
      end;

    if (edPassword.Text = '') then
      begin
        edPassword.SetFocus;
        Label4.Caption := 'Password required.';
        Exit;
      end;

    if (edPort.Text = '') then
      begin
        edPort.SetFocus;
        Label4.Caption := 'Port required.';
        Exit;
      end;

    myFTP.Host := edHost.Text;
    myFTP.Username := edUser.Text;
    myFTP.Password := edPassword.Text;
    myFTP.Port := StrToInt(edPort.Text);

    if (ckbUseSSL.Checked) then
      begin
        myFTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
        myFTP.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
        myFTP.Passive := True;
      end
    else
      begin
        myFTP.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsClear;
        myFTP.UseTLS := utNoTLSSupport;
        myFTP.Passive := False;
      end;


    myFTP.Connect;
    Label4.Caption := 'Connected';
    Label2.Caption := '';
  except on e:Exception do
    begin
      Label4.Caption := 'Failed to connect';
      Label2.Caption := e.Message;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label2.Caption := '';
  Label4.Caption := '';
end;

end.
```

Here's the dfm:

```dfm
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 568
  ClientWidth = 704
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 120
    Top = 101
    Width = 496
    Height = 44
    AutoSize = False
    Caption = '[...]'
    WordWrap = True
  end
  object Label4: TLabel
    Left = 120
    Top = 72
    Width = 20
    Height = 13
    Caption = '[...]'
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 120
    Top = 37
    Width = 22
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Host'
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Left = 272
    Top = 37
    Width = 22
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'User'
  end
  object Label5: TLabel
    Left = 456
    Top = 37
    Width = 32
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'PWord'
  end
  object Label6: TLabel
    Left = 605
    Top = 37
    Width = 20
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Port'
  end
  object btnConnectFTP: TButton
    Left = 32
    Top = 32
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Connect'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = btnConnectFTPClick
  end
  object mem: TMemo
    Left = 113
    Top = 160
    Width = 503
    Height = 377
    ScrollBars = ssVertical
    TabOrder = 1
    WordWrap = False
  end
  object btnShowFolder: TButton
    Left = 32
    Top = 160
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Show Folder'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = btnShowFolderClick
  end
  object edHost: TEdit
    Left = 148
    Top = 32
    Width = 105
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object edUser: TEdit
    Left = 300
    Top = 32
    Width = 137
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 4
  end
  object edPassword: TEdit
    Left = 495
    Top = 32
    Width = 90
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 5
  end
  object edPort: TEdit
    Left = 633
    Top = 32
    Width = 40
    Height = 21
    NumbersOnly = True
    TabOrder = 6
    Text = '21'
  end
  object ckbUseSSL: TCheckBox
    Left = 40
    Top = 72
    Width = 57
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'Use SSL'
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    MaxLineAction = maException
    DefaultPort = 0
    ReadTimeout = 60000
    SSLOptions.Mode = sslmClient
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
    Left = 69
    Top = 318
  end
  object myFTP: TIdFTP
    IOHandler = idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    IPVersion = Id_IPv4
    ConnectTimeout = 0
    NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive = False
    NATKeepAlive.IdleTimeMS = 0
    NATKeepAlive.IntervalMS = 0
    ProxySettings.ProxyType = fpcmNone
    ProxySettings.Port = 0
    Left = 22
    Top = 278
  end
  object idAntiFreeze: TIdAntiFreeze
    Left = 24
    Top = 216
  end
end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Setting the `UseTLS` property *may* change the `Port` property, so make sure you are actually connecting to the correct port you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. I checked the port, and it is still set to 21 (which is what the hosting company specified). Still getting the same 10054 error.

Comment: 10054 is an abortive disconnect from the remote peer. It is difficult to diagnose this kind of issue without knowing more about your setup, and maybe a capture of the raw socket traffic back and forth. Which exact line of code is failing? Are you using Active or Passive mode transfers? What do you have the `DataPortProtection` property set to?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I edited the question to add the full source of where I am. The only difference between this code and what was working with my old host is that this includes the attempt to use SSL (which may be unnecessary). As this used to work, I've never had to deal with investigating "raw socket traffic"...where do I go to get that? Thanks!

Comment: You are not setting the `TIdFTP.DataPortProtection` property to `ftpdpsPrivate` to enable SSL on the transfer port when enabling SSL via `UseTLS` on the command port.  Also, the `TIdFTP.Passive` property defaults to False, which means the FTP server connects to `TIdFTP` for transfer connections. Try setting `TIdFTP.Passive` to True instead so `TIdFTP` connect to the FTP server instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I updated the code above with the changes you suggested, but still getting the 10054 error.

Are there properties that need to be set in the TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL object? If so, which ones and what values?

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing all SLL methodes/types by setting the correct properties (dont remember the actual property names) of `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`.

Comment: You are thinking of the `SSLOptions.Method` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` properties

Comment: @skippix: Because you’r connecting to an other host, the supported SSL versions might be different. So allowing all versions will make sure this is not the problem.